# Have some bugs when implementing my own Atoi()

Tags: c, c11, atoi

I can't understand. While my function returning, from char in main, random number. Original atoi() returning -1. I'm currently using C11 version. I heard from someone, that's because of int overflow and i need return int from my function, but i'm currently returning long. How can i detect intOverflow if that's not a 2147483647

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool mx_isdigit(int c) {
    return c >= 48 && c <= 57;
}


bool mx_isspace(char c) {
    return (c >= 9 && c <= 13) || c == 32;
}


int mx_atoi(const char *str) {
    long num = 0;
    int sign = 1;

    for (; mx_isspace(*str); str++);

    if (*str == '-' || *str == '+') {
        sign = *str == '-' ? -sign : sign;
        str++;
    }

    for (; *str; str++) {
        if (!mx_isdigit(*str)) {
            break;
        }
        num = (num * 10) + (*str - '0');
    }
    return sign == -1 ? -num : 0 + num;
}

int main(void) {

    char str[100] = "12327123061232712306";
    printf("R: %d\n", atoi(str));
    printf("M: %d", mx_atoi(str));
}
```

Comment: Um you could make sign = -sign. It will be like 5 = -5

Comment: Yes, i think i need to detect overflow. But the thing is. If char would be in one digit less than 12327123061232712306. Original atoi() give me a random number instead of -1.

Comment: Minor note: it's a really good idea to use actual characters instead of the numeric ASCII values; it's way too easy to make a mistake: `return c >= '0' && c <= '9';`  Even better would be to use the `<ctype.h>` macros, which already has `isdigit()` and `isspace()` and others.

Comment: It's true, that it is easy to use '0' and '9'. But what if we want to check white spaces instead? '\n' '\t' '  ' and etc?

Comment: Use `'\n'` for newline, `'\t'` for tab, etc. But do look into the ctype macros, because they probably have what you need already

Comment: Unrelated to your question, always check against null termination everywhere. That is: `while(*str != '\0' && mx_isspace(*str))
    {
      str++;
    }` and so on.

Comment: In most experiments, i saw that *str checking null terminator by itself. Maybe i wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your function `int mx_atoi(const char *str) {...`, you are calculating a result of type `long`, yet the function returns an `int`; so if the result stored in `num` of type `long` does not fit in an `int`, something will get lost (actually , since signed integral values are converted, the behaviour is "implementation-defined", i.e. compiler-dependant). The result could be truncated bitwise, yielding a number that "looks" rather different that the decimal number you entered. Cf., for example, [this](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3) online C11 draft. The bold paragraph applies:

> **6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**
>
> 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type
>   other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it
>   is unchanged.
>
> 2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by
>   repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
>   can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
>   the new type.60)
>
> **3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be
>   represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an
>   implementation-defined signal is raised.**

Make `int mx_atoi(const char *str)` to `long mx_atoi(const char *str)`, use a `long`-variable to store the result, and don't forget to use format specifier `%ld` instead of `%d` in your `printf` then.

Otherwise, if you need to stick to `int` and you want to safely react on overflows, you could do something like

```
if (num > INT_MAX) {
  return -1;
}
```

inside your loop. `INT_MAX` is defined in `limits.h`

Comment: I want to be that function to be int. How can i make it like that?

Comment: then you simply cannot return values larger then MAX_INT, and you'd need to check inside your function if `long num` is larger than `MAX_INT` and react in some defined way.

Comment: Okay, i've changed function to long type. I'm using clang compiler. But it still gives me a random number instead of -1. Oh, okay. Now i see edited answer

Comment: you still can overflow `long` then; before doing `num *= 10`, you need to check `if (num >= (LONG_MAX/10)) { return -1; }`

Comment: `long` and in select cases `long long`, `unsigned` have the same positive range as `int`.  To handle all, overflow detection needs to rely on `int` math. Code like `if (num >= (LONG_MAX/10))` is insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

> c >= 48 && c <= 57

Do not use magic numbers in the code. Instead of `48` use `'0'` which is way more readable and provides what intention your do.

> How can i detect intOverflow

Overflow happens when the result is greater then the maximum a type can represent. So having numbers `a` and `b` we can write:

```
a + b > MAX
```

But such condition could not be checked, because `a + b`... will overflow. But if we flip the expression:

```
b > MAX - a
```

Can be easily checked with a simple `if`. `MAX` is the maximum value for a type, for `int` that is `INT_MAX` from `limits.h`.

```
int mx_atoi(const char *str) {    
    for (; mx_isspace(*str); str++);

    bool negative = false;
    if (*str == '-' || *str == '+') {
        negative = *str == '-';
        str++;
    }

    int num = 0;
    for (; mx_isdigit(*str); str++) {
        if (INT_MAX / 10 < num) {
            goto ERR_OVERFLOW;
        }
        num *= 10;
        const unsigned char c = *str - '0';
        if (INT_MAX - c < num) {
            goto ERR_OVERFLOW;
        }
        num += c;

    }
    return negative ? -num : num;
    ERR_OVERFLOW:
    return negative ? INT_MIN : INT_MAX;
}
```

Comment: In C11, atoi() does not return INT_MIN, INT_MAX.

Comment: @AntonZhukov Disagree with "In C11, atoi() does not return INT_MIN, INT_MAX."  In C11, C89, C99, C18, with 32-bit `int`,  `atoi("‭2147483647‬")` certainly returns `INT_MAX`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Clever use of `if (INT_MAX - c < num) {
            goto ERR_OVERFLOW;` to generate `INT_MIN` ever when the conversion of `mx_atoi("‭-2147483648‬")` was in range on `int`.  UV  LSNED

Comment: BTW: could simplify with  `bool negative = *str == '-'; if (*str == '-' || *str == '+')  str++;`, yet exiting code is instructive.

Answer (score 0):

**`int` overflow potential**

`num = (num * 10) + (*str - '0');` encounters `int` overflow, which is *undefined behavior* (UB)  when:

1) input string should represent `INT_MIN` and `int/long` have the same range OR
2) input string encodes a value outside the `int` range.

Various ways to avoid that.

**Does not detect a string of no digits**

Returning 0 in that case is reasonable, yet code may want to set some error condition.

**Does not complain about trailing non-digits**

Simply ignoring trailing characters is reasonable, yet code may want to set some error condition.

---

A way to avoid `int` overflow (and *not* rely on `long` wider than `int`) is to test before `(num * 10) + (*str - '0')` and since there is more negative `int`s than positive ones, accumulate on the negative side.

```
bool digit_found = false;
int val = 0;
for (; mx_isdigit(*str); str++) {
    digit_found = true;
    int digit = *str - '\0';
    if (val <= INT_MIN/10 && (val < INT_MIN/10 || digit > -(INT_MIN%10))) { // C99
      return sign == 1 ? INT_MAX : INT_MIN;
    }
    val = val * 10 - digit;  // note subtraction here
}

if (!digit_found) {
    return 0; // Or handle in some other fashion
}

if (sign == 1) {
  // If val is too negative to negate ...
  if (val < -INT_MAX) {
    return INT_MAX;  // overflow
  }
  return -val;
}
return val;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way, that i guessed. atoi() original using `LLONG_MAX` check instead of `LONG_MAX` or `INT_MAX`. So, experimenting with those limits i discovered. That if `(num * 10) + (*str - '0')` will reach over the limit of `long long` type, it will transform number to negative value of `LLONG_MIN`. So, i have created if statement, that check if next calculation will be less than previous. And if it's true, returning 0 or -1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool mx_isdigit(int c);
bool mx_isspace(char c);

int mx_atoi(const char* str) {
    long long num = 0;
    int sign = 1;

    for (; mx_isspace(*str); str++);

    if (*str == '-' || *str == '+') {
        sign = *str == '-' ? -sign : sign;
        str++;
    }

    for (; *str; str++) {
        if (!mx_isdigit(*str)) {
            break;
        }
```

> ```
>       if ((num * 10) + (*str - '0') < num) {
>           return sign == -1 ? 0 : -1;
>       }
> ```

```
        num = (num * 10) + (*str - '0');
    }

    return sign == -1 ? -num : num;
}

int main(void) {

    char str[100] = "-9223372036854775809";
    printf("R: %d\n", atoi(str));
    printf("M: %d\n", mx_atoi(str));
}
```